# Change icon on click (toggle)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple script in jquery to toggle a div (show and hide) when a `<p>` is clicked (I'm using bootstrap).

HTML:

```
<p id="click_advance"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-down"></i> Advanced search</p>
<div id="display_advance">
    <p>This is the advance search</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#click_advance').click(function(){
$('#display_advance').toggle('1000');
$(this).html('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-up"></i> Advanced search');
```

});

So, when I click for the first time the icon changes from down to up but obviously when I click "click_advance" again the icon doesn't change back. So I want the toggle effect like the show and hide; but I'm cluless on how to do it with an icon.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the html every time, just toggle the class.

```
$('#click_advance').click(function() {
    $('#display_advance').toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-circle-arrow-up icon-circle-arrow-down");
});
```

Answer (score 9):

If your icon is based on the text in the  block (ligatures) rather the class of the  block then the following will work. This example uses the Google Material Icons '+' and '-' icons as part of MaterializeCSS.

```
<a class="btn-class"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>

$('.btn-class').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).find('i').text() == 'add'){
        $(this).find('i').text('remove');
    } else {
        $(this).find('i').text('add');
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Added missing `);` needed for this to function properly.

It also works for JQuery post 1.9 where toggling of functions was deprecated.

Comment: Worked great for me! Also works when icon is nested into other divs.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$('#click_advance').click(function(){
  $('#display_advance').toggle('1000');
  icon = $(this).find("i");
  icon.hasClass("icon-circle-arrow-down"){
    icon.addClass("icon-circle-arrow-up").removeClass("icon-circle-arrow-down");
  }else{
    icon.addClass("icon-circle-arrow-down").removeClass("icon-circle-arrow-up");
  }
})
```

or even better, as Kevin said:

```
$('#click_advance').click(function(){
  $('#display_advance').toggle('1000');
  icon = $(this).find("i");
  icon.toggleClass("icon-circle-arrow-up icon-circle-arrow-down")
})
```

Answer (score 4):

If .toggle is not working I would do the next:

```
var flag = false;
$('#click_advance').click(function(){
    if( flag == false){
       $('#display_advance').show('1000');
         // Add more code
       flag = true;
    }
    else{
       $('#display_advance').hide('1000');
       // Add more code
       flag = false;
    }
}
```

It's a little bit more code, but it works

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very easy way of doing that

```
 $(function () {
    $(".glyphicon").unbind('click');
    $(".glyphicon").click(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Just a small fix: add }); at the end. Thank you for the solution Yj

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#togglebutton").click(function () {
  $(".fa-arrow-circle-left").toggleClass("fa-arrow-circle-right");
}
```

I have a button with the id "togglebutton" and an icon from FontAwesome . This can be a way to toggle it . from left arrow to right arrow icon