# Changing icons in an accordion with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

How can I change the arrow down icon ( [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GJV4.jpg) ) to an arrow up icon ( [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yRfg.jpg) ) when that dd is opened. If another skill bar is clicked and some other dd is opened(the first one automatically closes) the first icon should change back to arrow down. This is the class for the arrow up icon: ion-arrow-up-b.

HTML code:

```
<div class="containers-right">
    <dl class="accordion">
        <dt>
            <i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
            <div class="skill-container desktop">  
                <div class="skill learning"></div> 
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <p class="accordion-text">Info about Learning skill</p>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
            <div class="skill-container desktop"> 
                <div class="skill organization">
                </div> 
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <p class="accordion-text">Info about Organization skill</p>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
            <div class="skill-container desktop"> 
                <div class="skill creativity"></div> 
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <p class="accordion-text">Info about Creativity skill</p>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
            <div class="skill-container desktop"> 
                <div class="skill communication"></div> 
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <p class="accordion-text">Info about Communication skill</p>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
            <div class="skill-container desktop"> 
                <div class="skill teamwork"></div> 
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <p class="accordion-text">Info about Teamwork skill</p>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.accordion{
    width: 10em;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.accordion,
.accordion dt{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.accordion dd{
    margin: -0.55em 0 0.55em 0;
}

dt{
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-container{ text-align: left; }

.accordion-text{
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #4f285f;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.2em 0.5em;
}

.ion-arrow-down-b,
.ion-arrow-up-b{
    color: #6a6868;
    margin-left: -1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-top: -0.35em;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
var accordion = $('.accordion');

accordion.find('dd').hide();

accordion.find('dt').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open').next('dd').slideToggle().siblings('dd:visible').slideUp().prev('dt').removeClass('open');     
});
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345784/change-icon-on-click-toggle

Comment: It solved my problem partialy. When i open one panel the icon changes to arrow up, and when i click it again to close it the icon returns to arrow down. But, when one panel is opened and I click another, the first icon doesn't return to arrow down.