# Change toggle icon on click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to jquery, trying to switch font awesome icons upon toggle click on my rails 5 app. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345784/change-icon-on-click-toggle) question to implement the feature, but I'm not seeing the icon change effect.

```
<h2>Spanish <i id="click-spanish" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></h2>

<div id="spanish-examples" class="initiallyHidden">
  etc.
</div>
```

And the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click-spanish').click(function() {
    $('#spanish-examples').toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-caret-up");
  });
});
```

Removing `this` above achieves the result, but all other icons on the page change as well.

Comment: This solved it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click-spanish').click(function() {
    $('#spanish-examples').toggle('1000');
    //"this" is the click-spanish icon, since you are inside the click handler
    //for that element.  You just have to use it, not try to find it.
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-caret-up");
  });
});
```