# Why the dark-theme colors written in the SCSS file does not apply?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize, darkmode

I'm trying to add a dark-theme toggle button to my page, i looked up in the internet for code and i saw the example below. i copied the code to my VS code editor and when i am clicking the toggle button, it's icon changing but the window stays white

i took the code from this codepen site and removed all the non-relevant html elements:
https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/MRbpLX

this is the code:

```js
// SIDENAV
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();


  // SWAP ICON ON CLICK
  // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254979/751570
  $('.dark-toggle').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).find('i').text() == 'brightness_4') {
      $(this).find('i').text('brightness_high');
    } else {
      $(this).find('i').text('brightness_4');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
/* and this is the dark_mode.scss file, compiled to css */

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: color 1s ease, background-color 1s ease;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #202123;
  color: #fff;
}

body.dark nav {
  background-color: #26A69A;
}

body.dark .card {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

body.dark .btn {
  background-color: #EE6F73;
}

body.dark .divider {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

body.dark .sidenav {
  background-color: #2D2D31;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a:not(.subheader) {
  color: #89B2F5;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a:not(.subheader):hover {
  background-color: #3B4043;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a.subheader {
  color: #9AA0A6;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a .material-icons {
  color: #9AA0A6;
}

body.dark .collection {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

body.dark .collection .collection-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dark_mode.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="dark_mode.scss">
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />

</head>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <a class="btn dark-toggle" href="#" onclick="localStorage.setItem('mode', (localStorage.getItem('mode') || 'dark') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'); localStorage.getItem('mode') === 'dark' ? document.querySelector('body').classList.add('dark') : document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('dark')"
      title="Dark/light"><i class="material-icons left">brightness_4</i> Toggle Dark Mode</a>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: You've probably stripped down the HTML too much, the `body` element is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your dark mode toggle function, you need to toggle the class `dark` on the `body` element. Also, in your markup, you cannot omit the `body` tag, it's mandatory and also, aside from `head`, the only child element allowed in `<html>`:

```
$('.dark-toggle').on('click',function(){
    // OTHER STUFF
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
});
```

```js
// SIDENAV
$(document).ready(function() {
  // SWAP ICON ON CLICK
  // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254979/751570
  $('.dark-toggle').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).find('i').text() == 'brightness_4') {
      $(this).find('i').text('brightness_high');
    } else {
      $(this).find('i').text('brightness_4');
    }
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
  });

});
```

```css
/* and this is the dark_mode.scss file, compiled to css */

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: color 1s ease, background-color 1s ease;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #202123;
  color: #fff;
}

body.dark nav {
  background-color: #26A69A;
}

body.dark .card {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

body.dark .btn {
  background-color: #EE6F73;
}

body.dark .divider {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

body.dark .sidenav {
  background-color: #2D2D31;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a:not(.subheader) {
  color: #89B2F5;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a:not(.subheader):hover {
  background-color: #3B4043;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a.subheader {
  color: #9AA0A6;
}

body.dark .sidenav li a .material-icons {
  color: #9AA0A6;
}

body.dark .collection {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

body.dark .collection .collection-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  
</head>

<body class="light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <a class="btn dark-toggle" href="#" title="Dark/light"><i class="material-icons left">brightness_4</i> Toggle Dark Mode</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that I have removed the `onclick` on the toggle as that is not permitted with StackOverflows snippet setup. That part is responsible for storing the current dark/light mode setting in the locas storage of the browser, as well as restoring it from there when you come back to the page next time.

Comment: i tried to change to the code you have written but still when i run the code, the button's icon changes but the page stays white and butotn stays green instead of red

Comment: You see it works when you run the snippet in my answer. I also noticed you're including `less.js` in your page - while your question suggests that you are using SCSS. Check your browser's developer tools console for errors.

Comment: yes i saw it works in the snippet, but i dont really know whats the difference, its somthing in the chrome settings i need to change or it somthing in the code that i can change in my VS code editor so it will work on every chrome on every computer aswell?

Comment: If you're on Windows, press F12 in Chrome and switch to the console tab in the developer tools. Check for any errors there. If there's no errors there, check the network tab, reload the page and see if all external ressources are loaded properly.

Comment: ok it worked, i changed your code to be .css and not .scss. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are missing the `body` tag in the HTML document. Also in your JS file, you need to change the class so that other styles can be applied

```
$('.dark-toggle').on('click',function(){
   let element = $(this).find('i');
    if ( element.text() === 'brightness_4')
        element.text('brightness_high');
    else
        element.text('brightness_4');
 
    $('body').toggleClass('dark');
});
```

Comment: i added that and tried to add the JS code you have entered but it still stays a white page when i click the button